# GridView.builder Instatiation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-gridview

I am trying to use GridView builder and I just don't know how to use it. I'm a Flutter noob and would appreciate it if you guys could help. So here's my GridView code:

```
Container(
              height: 400,
              child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return gridCard(card: card[index]);
                  }))
```

And I want these instantiations to appear instead as "Cards". Here are my codes:

**List**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:interstellar/Elements/gridCards.dart';

List<GridItem> card = [
  GridItem(
      spaceImg:
          ('https://images.pexels.com/photos/37347/office-sitting-room-executive-sitting.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2'),
      spaceName: 'Hive Net Work Hub',
      spacePrice: '25/hr',
      spaceAdd: 'E Lopez St. Brgy San Vicente Jaro'),
  GridItem(
      spaceImg:
          ('https://images.pexels.com/photos/2635038/pexels-photo-2635038.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2'),
      spaceName: 'Thinking Box Study Hub',
      spacePrice: '25/hr',
      spaceAdd: 'Timawa Street, Molo, Iloilo City, Philippines'),
];

class GridItem {
  final String spaceImg;
  final String spaceName;
  final String spacePrice;
  final String spaceAdd;

  const GridItem(
      {required this.spaceImg,
      required this.spaceName,
      required this.spacePrice,
      required this.spaceAdd});
}
```

**"Cards"**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:interstellar/Elements/gridItem.dart';

Widget gridCard({required GridItem card}) => Container(
        child: Column(children: [
      Expanded(
          child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9, child: Image.network(card.spaceImg))),
      SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      Row(
        children: [Text(card.spaceName)],
      ),
      Row(
        children: [Text(card.spacePrice)],
      ),
      Row(
        children: [Text(card.spaceAdd)],
      )
    ]));
```

**ERROR**

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 3
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 4
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 5
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 6
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 7
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

This is the error I'm getting. I'm pretty this isn't the right way to return the list and I don't know how.

Any help would be really great. I appreciate you all. Thank you.

Comment: is the console saying the above code has error? or the view built is not what you expected?

Comment: It does have an error, yes. I'll include that to the question. Thanks for responding.

Comment: add item count to your Gridview.builder method. it doesn't know how many items you have in your list.

Comment: you can do it like card.length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Grid.builder` need provide **itemCount** to be able to rendered.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final sample = List.generate(30, (i) => i);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
          itemCount: sample.length, // <-- required
          itemBuilder: (_, i) => Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Center(child: Text('${sample[i]}')),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. The itemCount: was indeed what I was missing. You such a lifesaver. Thank you.